# Store value from multiple select element value into array in MongoDB using mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

hi everyone thanks in advance,

I have an HTML form with a div element which has a select tag and two buttons for + and -. The user can click on the + button to duplicate select tag(up to 5 times). I need to store the value from select tag to store in MongoDB using mongoose. I am not sure how I can get this value in JS and store in the variable to pass into MongoDB.

**pug file**

```
div(id='divDay1')
            button.btnDay1(type='button' onclick='appendRow(this)') +
            button.btnDay1(type='button' onclick='removeRow(this)') -
            label(for='Day1') Day1:
            div
                Select#Day1.form-control1(type='select'  name='Day1' required='true' )
                    for task in tasks
                        option(value=task._id) #{task.TaskName}
```

// JS code

```
var x=1;
//Add select list
function appendRow(elem)
{
    //get parent node
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    //console.log(parent);
    //get last child element
    var l=parent.lastChild;
    //console.log(l);
    //var d = document.getElementById(parent.id);
    var s = document.getElementById( l.firstChild.id ).cloneNode(true);
    s.id = "Select"+x;    
    //var s1=document.getElementsByClassName("form-control1")
    //console.log(d);
    //console.log(s);
    //Add only 4 child elements
    if(l.childElementCount<4){l.appendChild(s);};     
    //increment x
    x++;
};
// remove select list
function removeRow(elem)
{
    //alert("JS file Load");
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    //get last child element
    var l=parent.lastChild;
    // remove last child element, Remove upto 1 element
    if(l.childElementCount>1){l.removeChild(l.lastChild);};  

};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this code snippet to get form data in an array

   function getSelectValArr() {

   ```
   var selectValArr = [];
   $(':input', $('#div1')).not('button').each(function() { selectValArr.push($(this).val());});
   return selectValArr;
   ```

   }

> Make sure jQuery has been included in your html.

2. Then use this array to send data to server.

   ```
   var setting = {url: 'your_api_url', data: {"someKey": 
   getSelectValArr() }, method: 'POST', success: function(response) {},error: function(error) {}};

   $.ajax(setting);
   ```